# Where do you put an object call that is needed before your application loads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object call that is basically initiating a singleton that is needed all over my application.  I thought the best place to put this was the environment.rb file, right after the Application.initialize! call.  And it had worked with all my tests.  But now that I'm running my code in the development environment, I'm finding that it is not getting called.  Is there somewhere else I should be putting it, or is there something wrong with my development environment setup?

EDIT: I haven't looked at the answers yet, but I did find out that it's not working in development when I have the config.cache_classes set to false.

Comment: How did you define the singleton?

Comment: I am not sure what can be causing the issue in development environment, but a better way can be to initialize the object in an initializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting it in an initializer file.

See this link for [configuring rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I do use config files written in `yml` and load these with an initializer.

If you don't want to go into details, use Ryan Bate's gem: [nifty-generators](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators)

and type in console:

```
rails g nifty:config
```

It will install everything for you. Then edit your `config/app_config.yml` file.